# How to move a large folder to s3?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for the most suitable tool to transfer 600 GB of media from a Linux server to s3, so far I found s3 sync and s3cmd , but they do not work in background mode, tell me the best option?

Comment: What do you understand by a "background mode"?

Comment: @Marcin i mean the daemon process so that it runs anyway until it recursively moves all the files because sync stops working as soon as i close the terminal

Comment: I would do as @Marcin suggested in the answer but you can make a deamon yourself very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your command in [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki), or [nohup](https://linuxhint.com/how_to_use_nohup_linux/). This way the AWS CLI command will persist after you logout. There are [other ways](https://linoxide.com/keep-processes-running-ssh-logout-linux/), but I personally find tmux being my preferred choice.